# 301 redirect not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I made a subdomain, and I am trying to redirect a page from the original domain to the subdomain, with the same dir structure.

My original page is this:

http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/alaska_hiking.php

I put this rule into the .htaaccess file under comehike.com/outdoors/ directory:

```
RewriteRule ^outdoors/alaska_hiking.php       http://hiking.comehike.com/outdoors/alaska_hiking.php [R,L]
```

But as you can see from visiting the original url, it doesn't redirect.  Any idea why?

Thanks!

I use apache server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That RewriteRule line works for me when I stick it in my .htaccess file, are you sure you have `RewriteEngine On`?